# ALM-UFT Integration not working

Tags: automation, hp-uft, alm

I am new to HP UFT-ALM integration. I have saved the test case from UFT to ALM Test Plan and moved that to test LAB. But while running its not getting executed and throw error as "The remote procedure call failed and did not execute"

Could you please suggest the issue ??

Comment: It may be due to the following reasons, 1. In UFT you have to set `Allow other HP Products to communicate / run` 2. In ALM when you run the test, are you running it locally? If so, do you have UFT in that machine?

Comment: check your UFT-ALM patches. if everything looks fine and if  this is not an frequent issue , so can close close run session and refresh the ALM then start your execution.  Sometimes i used to get this when i run the test scripts in batch. if you are doing the same then try to run one script and then other just for validation.  it is an adhoc issue that's what i have noticed.

Comment: @Barney I had done all pre-requisite you mentioned, still this error is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

its very common issue when running UFY-ALM for first time.

Navigate to Control Panel > User access setting. Change the setting level to minimum and restart UFT. It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All for sharing your input.

Actually it got ressolved when I have updated my UFT to version 14. In my opinion the issue was with the UFT-ALM add-ins installation. It actually comes with the installation pkg itself but it seems, for previous version this add-in was missed.